# Tab menu needing different outcomes when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following simple html that has a tab menu with some javascript to change content when tabs are clicked.

***test.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Menu Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "public/stylesheets/master.css";</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script><!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tablist > li > a').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor

       //get displaying tab content jQuery selector
       var active_tab_selector = $('.tablist > li.active > a').attr('href');                    

       //find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
       var actived_nav = $('.tablist > li.active');
       actived_nav.removeClass('active');

       //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
       $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

       //hide displaying tab content
       $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
       $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

       //show target tab content
       var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
       $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
       $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
    });
});
    //--></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page-container">
    <div id="main-nav">
        <ul class="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <section id="tab1" class="tab-content active">
            <div>
                Content for Tab1 
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab2" class="tab-content hide">
            <div>
                Content for Tab2
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab3" class="tab-content hide">
            <div>
                Content for Tab3
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***master.css***

```
.tablist { list-style: none; height: 30px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: none; }
.tablist li { float:left; margin-right: 3px; }
.tablist li a { display:block; padding:0 16px; text-decoration:none; border: 1px solid #babdb6; border-bottom:0; font:bold 14px/32px arial,geneva,helvetica,sans-serif; color:#000; background-color:#ccc;

/*===  CSS 3 elements  ===*/
webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tablist li a:hover { background:#babdb6; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }


.tablist > .active > a,
.tablist > .active > a:hover { color: #555555; cursor: default; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-color: transparent; }

.tab-content.active{ display: block; }

.tab-content.hide{ display: none; }
```

When I click on Tab1, Tab2 or Tab3 I get the relevant div being displayed and the others being hidden.  I do want this functionality unless there is a better way of including different content based on the tab that was clicked.  If there is a better way to do this I would appreciate a heads up, however that is probably for a different question.

***My Question for now:***
I would like to run a different action if you will when I click on the Logout tab.  However I still want that logout tab to look the same as the others.  Is there a way that when I click the logout tab the url "/logout" actually takes me too the logout page (not provided in this example) instead of trying to hide dive like the other tabs do?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `$('.tablist > li > a')` will find all anchor tags nested within the 'tablist' class object. This **includes** your logout tag`<a href="/logout">Logout</a>`.  This is why your logout tab acts like the other tabs.

There are several methods to exclude the logout tab from that loop. The easiest method off the top of my head is to give the anchor an ID and use a `:not` selector:

```
<a id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Your new loop selector would look like this:

```
$('.tablist > li > a').not('#logout')
```

Once you exclude the tab from that code, you should be able to handle it separately to have it redirect to the page you want.

Comment: Ahhh gee I wish I could up vote.  This makes great sense. Thank you.  I can't wait to test.  I am assuming I can do something like. $('.tabling > li > a').not ('#logout').click (...

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of excluding the logout button from the click function entirely, and writing its own handler (as @xCRKxTyPHoon shows), however, if you desire to still use that click function, and want to be able to add more links in the same fashion without having to write separate handlers for each, you could add something like this at the start of the click function (checks if the href attribute has a slash, and redirects if it does):

```
if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('/') !== -1){
  window.location = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

Here's a pen with that in there: http://codepen.io/shigidaMark/pen/YqNWRy

Comment: Another good suggestion. Thanks for the one as well .... nice to see it in operation. Sorry I can't up vote yet.